# Symfony 4 - KnpPaginatorBundle use a global list and filtered list

Tags: php, symfony, paginator

I decided to use the KnpPaginatorBundle bundle.

In a page, I display by default all my users.
But I added a form at the top of the list to enter a particular name. When submitting the form, I retrieve the name filled in my controller, and I use the paginator again to filter on my users and display the new list.

Except that when this happens, if I go to page 2, it shows me again page 2 but on all of my users.
And I do not see how I can make sure that it shows me the good pages if I filter the names.

Here is my files :

**Controller**:

```
 /**
     * Undocumented function
     * 
     * @Route("/rh2", name="rh_index2")
     *
     * @param PaginatorInterface $paginator
     * @param Request $request
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     * @param UserRepository $repo
     * @return void
     */
    public function index2(PaginatorInterface $paginator, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager, UserRepository $repo)
    {
        $name = $request->get('champRecherche');

        if ($name != null) {
            $token = $request->get('token');
            if (!$this->isCsrfTokenValid('rh_index2', $token)) {
                throw new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException('Accès interdit');
            }

            //$pagination = $repoUser->getUsersByName($name);
            $users = $repo->getUsersFiltered($name);
            $appointments = $paginator->paginate(
                $users,
                $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
                1
            );
        } else {

            $users = $repo->findAll();

            $appointments = $paginator->paginate(
                $users,
                $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
                5
            );
        }

        return $this->render('rh/index2.html.twig', [
            'appointments' => $appointments
        ]);
    }
```

**Twig**:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

    <form action="{{ path('rh_index2') }}" method="POST">

        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('rh_index2') }}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Entrer le nom de l'utilisateur" type="text" name="champRecherche" id="champRecherche"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="search" value="Chercher">Chercher</button>
                <a href="{{ path('rh_index2') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Afficher tous</a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form><br>
    <table class="table table-hover align-items-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Service</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for user in appointments %}
                <tr>
                    <th>{{user.fullName}}</th>
                    <th>{{user.groupe.nom}}</th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Voir</a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="navigation">
        {{knp_pagination_render(appointments)}}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Let your form use GET method so that name=Frank comes into the URL.